# Netbeans project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jfugue

I am Java beginner. I have developed only two Java desktop applications and I use Eclipse as IDE. Right now I wanted to work on this project https://nbjfuguesupport.dev.java.net/
All code is in Netbeans. I suceeded to import all libraries that are used in source files in eclipse, and I have no errors showing in code in Eclipse. The problem is that I don't know how to run that code from eclipse. I don't know which class has main method.

Using google I found out that Netbeans uses org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.main to start projects, but I cant't find this in my libraries. Does anyone know in which .jar does this class come with netbeans 5.5 files. ??

Regards.

P.S. I must use Eclipse because I have a team of 3 men who have also only used Eclipse in the past, and we need this code to help us in similar project for college.

Comment: NetBeans isn't *that* different from Eclipse.

Comment: Somehow it strikes me as a bit odd to insist on developing a project based on the Netbeans Platform in Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the core.jar file that contains Main class under:

C:\Program Files\NetBeans 5.5\platform10\core\

You can simply include that in your Eclipse Java Build path.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Now I have the error complaining about netbeans.user property not being set when I try to run from Eclipse.

Comment: Try running in NetBeans; you'll save yourself a lot of trouble configuring the project, and the learning curve coming from Eclipse isn't that steep.